# Building a DXF file from graphical objects

Tags: javascript, beginner, dojo

As a complete "newbie" to JavaScript when I started a project, I did actually manage to get what I needed to to work, but it is VERY clunky and inelegant.

I am hoping someone may be able to help me with cleaning some of the iterables I have that build a DXF (drawing exchange file) file. The DXF is importable into Autocad but is just a text file with a specific format. My code takes the user graphic polygons and extracts the coordinates into x,y from and too segments that in the end are downloadable as a complete file.

```
 on(dom.byId("getUnitsDXF"), "click", exportDXFUnits);
  function exportDXFUnits() {
      /*add in pop-up if user selects too many units*/
      if (graLyrUnits.graphics.length > 16) {
      alert("You can only select up to 16 units per dxf file");
      return;
            }
      /*create the coordinate string to parse to dxf file*/
    var unitCounter = graLyrUnits.graphics.length;
    var dxfString = "";
    var dxfNameString = "";
    for (i = 0; i < graLyrUnits.graphics.length; i++) {
        /*generate a list of coord values to create an array*/
        dxfString = dxfString + graLyrUnits.graphics[i].attributes["Coords"]+ ",";
        var string = dxfString;
        var coord_array = string.split(",");
        /*alert(coord_array);*/

        /* generate a list of name values to create another array*/
        dxfNameString = dxfNameString + graLyrUnits.graphics[i].attributes["name"]+ ",";
        var string = dxfNameString;
        var name_array = string.split(",");
        /*alert(name_array);*/

        /* assemble the coord string into dxf file chunks*/
        var oneUnit = (coord_array[0])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[1])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[2])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[3])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[2])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[3])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[4])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[5])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[4])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[5])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[6])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[7])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[6])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[7])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[8])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[9])+'\r\n  0\r\nTEXT\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[0])+'\r\n  20\r\n'+(coord_array[1])+'\r\n  40\r\n85.0\r\n  1\r\n'+(name_array[0])+'\r\n';
        var twoUnit = (dxfNextUnit)+(coord_array[10])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[11])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[12])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[13])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[12])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[13])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[14])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[15])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[14])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[15])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[16])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[17])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[16])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[17])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[18])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[19])+'\r\n  0\r\nTEXT\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[18])+'\r\n  20\r\n'+(coord_array[19])+'\r\n  40\r\n85.0\r\n  1\r\n'+(name_array[1])+'\r\n';
        var threeUnit = (dxfNextUnit)+(coord_array[20])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[21])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[22])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[23])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[22])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[23])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[24])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[25])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[24])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[25])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[26])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[27])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[26])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[27])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[28])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[29])+'\r\n  0\r\nTEXT\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[28])+'\r\n  20\r\n'+(coord_array[29])+'\r\n  40\r\n85.0\r\n  1\r\n'+(name_array[2])+'\r\n';
        var fourUnit = (dxfNextUnit)+(coord_array[30])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[31])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[32])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[33])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[32])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[33])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[34])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[35])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[34])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[35])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[36])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[37])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[36])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[37])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[38])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[39])+'\r\n  0\r\nTEXT\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[38])+'\r\n  20\r\n'+(coord_array[39])+'\r\n  40\r\n85.0\r\n  1\r\n'+(name_array[3])+'\r\n';
        var fiveUnit = (dxfNextUnit)+(coord_array[40])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[41])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[42])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[43])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[42])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[43])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[44])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[45])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[44])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[45])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[46])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[47])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[46])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[47])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[48])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[49])+'\r\n  0\r\nTEXT\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[48])+'\r\n  20\r\n'+(coord_array[49])+'\r\n  40\r\n85.0\r\n  1\r\n'+(name_array[4])+'\r\n';
        var sixUnit = (dxfNextUnit)+(coord_array[50])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[51])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[52])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[53])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[52])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[53])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[54])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[55])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[54])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[55])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[56])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[57])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[56])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[57])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[58])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[59])+'\r\n  0\r\nTEXT\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[58])+'\r\n  20\r\n'+(coord_array[59])+'\r\n  40\r\n85.0\r\n  1\r\n'+(name_array[5])+'\r\n';
        var sevenUnit = (dxfNextUnit)+(coord_array[60])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[61])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[62])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[63])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[62])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[63])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[64])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[65])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[64])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[65])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[66])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[67])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[66])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[67])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[68])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[69])+'\r\n  0\r\nTEXT\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[68])+'\r\n  20\r\n'+(coord_array[69])+'\r\n  40\r\n85.0\r\n  1\r\n'+(name_array[6])+'\r\n';
        var eightUnit = (dxfNextUnit)+(coord_array[70])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[71])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[72])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[73])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[72])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[73])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[74])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[75])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[74])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[75])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[76])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[77])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[76])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[77])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[78])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[79])+'\r\n  0\r\nTEXT\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[78])+'\r\n  20\r\n'+(coord_array[79])+'\r\n  40\r\n85.0\r\n  1\r\n'+(name_array[7])+'\r\n';
        var nineUnit = (dxfNextUnit)+(coord_array[80])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[81])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[82])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[83])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[82])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[83])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[84])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[85])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[84])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[85])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[86])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[87])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[86])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[87])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[88])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[89])+'\r\n  0\r\nTEXT\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[88])+'\r\n  20\r\n'+(coord_array[89])+'\r\n  40\r\n85.0\r\n  1\r\n'+(name_array[8])+'\r\n';
        var tenUnit = (dxfNextUnit)+(coord_array[90])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[91])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[92])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[93])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[92])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[93])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[94])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[95])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[94])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[95])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[96])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[97])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[96])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[97])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[98])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[99])+'\r\n  0\r\nTEXT\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[98])+'\r\n  20\r\n'+(coord_array[99])+'\r\n  40\r\n85.0\r\n  1\r\n'+(name_array[9])+'\r\n';
        var elevenUnit = (dxfNextUnit)+(coord_array[100])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[101])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[102])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[103])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[102])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[103])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[104])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[105])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[104])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[105])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[106])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[107])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[106])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[107])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[108])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[109])+'\r\n  0\r\nTEXT\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[108])+'\r\n  20\r\n'+(coord_array[109])+'\r\n  40\r\n85.0\r\n  1\r\n'+(name_array[10])+'\r\n';
        var twelveUnit = (dxfNextUnit)+(coord_array[110])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[111])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[112])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[113])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[112])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[113])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[114])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[115])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[114])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[115])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[116])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[117])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[116])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[117])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[118])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[119])+'\r\n  0\r\nTEXT\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[118])+'\r\n  20\r\n'+(coord_array[119])+'\r\n  40\r\n85.0\r\n  1\r\n'+(name_array[11])+'\r\n';
        var thirteenUnit = (dxfNextUnit)+(coord_array[120])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[121])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[122])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[123])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[122])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[123])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[124])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[125])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[124])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[125])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[126])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[127])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[126])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[127])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[128])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[129])+'\r\n  0\r\nTEXT\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[128])+'\r\n  20\r\n'+(coord_array[129])+'\r\n  40\r\n85.0\r\n  1\r\n'+(name_array[12])+'\r\n';
        var fourteenUnit = (dxfNextUnit)+(coord_array[130])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[131])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[132])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[133])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[132])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[133])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[134])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[135])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[134])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[135])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[136])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[137])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[136])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[137])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[138])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[139])+'\r\n  0\r\nTEXT\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[138])+'\r\n  20\r\n'+(coord_array[139])+'\r\n  40\r\n85.0\r\n  1\r\n'+(name_array[13])+'\r\n';
        var fifteenUnit = (dxfNextUnit)+(coord_array[140])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[141])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[142])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[143])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[142])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[143])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[144])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[145])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[144])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[145])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[146])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[147])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[146])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[147])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[148])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[149])+'\r\n  0\r\nTEXT\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[148])+'\r\n  20\r\n'+(coord_array[149])+'\r\n  40\r\n85.0\r\n  1\r\n'+(name_array[14])+'\r\n';
        var sixteenUnit = (dxfNextUnit)+(coord_array[150])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[151])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[152])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[153])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[152])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[153])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[154])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[155])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[154])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[155])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[156])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[157])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[156])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[157])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[158])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[159])+'\r\n  0\r\nTEXT\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[158])+'\r\n  20\r\n'+(coord_array[159])+'\r\n  40\r\n85.0\r\n  1\r\n'+(name_array[15])+'\r\n';

        var dxfHeader = '  0\r\nSECTION\r\n  2\r\nENTITIES\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n';
        var dxfNextUnit = '  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n';
        var dxfCloser = '  0\r\nENDSEC\r\n  0\r\nEOF';
      }
    if (unitCounter == 1) {
    download_file('data.dxf', 'text/dxf', (dxfHeader)+(oneUnit)+(dxfCloser));
        }
        else if (unitCounter == 2) {
        download_file('data.dxf', 'text/dxf', (dxfHeader)+(oneUnit)+(twoUnit)+(dxfCloser));
        }
        else if (unitCounter == 3) {
        download_file('data.dxf', 'text/dxf', (dxfHeader)+(oneUnit)+(twoUnit)+(threeUnit)+(dxfCloser));
        }
        else if (unitCounter == 4) {
        download_file('data.dxf', 'text/dxf', (dxfHeader)+(oneUnit)+(twoUnit)+(threeUnit)+(fourUnit)+(dxfCloser));
        }
        else if (unitCounter == 5) {
        download_file('data.dxf', 'text/dxf', (dxfHeader)+(oneUnit)+(twoUnit)+(threeUnit)+(fourUnit)+(fiveUnit)+(dxfCloser));
        }
        else if (unitCounter == 6) {
        download_file('data.dxf', 'text/dxf', (dxfHeader)+(oneUnit)+(twoUnit)+(threeUnit)+(fourUnit)+(fiveUnit)+(sixUnit)+(dxfCloser));
        }
        else if (unitCounter == 7) {
        download_file('data.dxf', 'text/dxf', (dxfHeader)+(oneUnit)+(twoUnit)+(threeUnit)+(fourUnit)+(fiveUnit)+(sixUnit)+(sevenUnit)+(dxfCloser));
        }
        else if (unitCounter == 8) {
        download_file('data.dxf', 'text/dxf', (dxfHeader)+(oneUnit)+(twoUnit)+(threeUnit)+(fourUnit)+(fiveUnit)+(sixUnit)+(sevenUnit)+(eightUnit)+(dxfCloser));
        }
        else if (unitCounter == 9) {
        download_file('data.dxf', 'text/dxf', (dxfHeader)+(oneUnit)+(twoUnit)+(threeUnit)+(fourUnit)+(fiveUnit)+(sixUnit)+(sevenUnit)+(eightUnit)+(nineUnit)+(dxfCloser));
        }
        else if (unitCounter == 10) {
        download_file('data.dxf', 'text/dxf', (dxfHeader)+(oneUnit)+(twoUnit)+(threeUnit)+(fourUnit)+(fiveUnit)+(sixUnit)+(sevenUnit)+(eightUnit)+(nineUnit)+(tenUnit)+(dxfCloser));
        }
        else if (unitCounter == 11) {
        download_file('data.dxf', 'text/dxf', (dxfHeader)+(oneUnit)+(twoUnit)+(threeUnit)+(fourUnit)+(fiveUnit)+(sixUnit)+(sevenUnit)+(eightUnit)+(nineUnit)+(tenUnit)+(elevenUnit)+(dxfCloser));
        }
        else if (unitCounter == 12) {
        download_file('data.dxf', 'text/dxf', (dxfHeader)+(oneUnit)+(twoUnit)+(threeUnit)+(fourUnit)+(fiveUnit)+(sixUnit)+(sevenUnit)+(eightUnit)+(nineUnit)+(tenUnit)+(elevenUnit)+(twelveUnit)+(dxfCloser));
        }
        else if (unitCounter == 13) {
        download_file('data.dxf', 'text/dxf', (dxfHeader)+(oneUnit)+(twoUnit)+(threeUnit)+(fourUnit)+(fiveUnit)+(sixUnit)+(sevenUnit)+(eightUnit)+(nineUnit)+(tenUnit)+(elevenUnit)+(twelveUnit)+(thirteenUnit)+(dxfCloser));
        }
        else if (unitCounter == 14) {
        download_file('data.dxf', 'text/dxf', (dxfHeader)+(oneUnit)+(twoUnit)+(threeUnit)+(fourUnit)+(fiveUnit)+(sixUnit)+(sevenUnit)+(eightUnit)+(nineUnit)+(tenUnit)+(elevenUnit)+(twelveUnit)+(thirteenUnit)+(fourteenUnit)+(dxfCloser));
        }
        else if (unitCounter == 15) {
        download_file('data.dxf', 'text/dxf', (dxfHeader)+(oneUnit)+(twoUnit)+(threeUnit)+(fourUnit)+(fiveUnit)+(sixUnit)+(sevenUnit)+(eightUnit)+(nineUnit)+(tenUnit)+(elevenUnit)+(twelveUnit)+(thirteenUnit)+(fourteenUnit)+(fifteenUnit)+(dxfCloser));
        }
        else if (unitCounter == 16) {
        download_file('data.dxf', 'text/dxf', (dxfHeader)+(oneUnit)+(twoUnit)+(threeUnit)+(fourUnit)+(fiveUnit)+(sixUnit)+(sevenUnit)+(eightUnit)+(nineUnit)+(tenUnit)+(elevenUnit)+(twelveUnit)+(thirteenUnit)+(fourteenUnit)+(fifteenUnit)+(sixteenUnit)+(dxfCloser));
        }
    else { 
    alert("You must select units to download");
    }
  }
```

Comment: is `coord_array[19]` set to `85`? if not, why does `unitOne` have that value in the second to last value?

Comment: Hi Sam - short answer is no. The coord_array is built for the x & y values of the vertices of the polygon (using a static field called Coord_string). the 85 is part of the text notation of the dxf file that needs to be built around the values

Comment: Hi Sam - tried out the code and it creates individual dxf files (one for each unit selected) but it is not populating the coordinates into the files - all entries are tagged as "1"   CONTINUOUS
 62
1
 10
1
 20
1
 11
1
 21
1
  0
LINE
  8
Unit
  6
CONTINUOUS
 62
1
 10
1
 20
1
 11
1
 21
1
  0     - Any ideas on why the array would not be populated?

Comment: I don't feel like I have enough information to answer that question. `coord_array` and `name_array` are still coming from the same source (and not the sample variables I made in my sample code), right? I presume you aren't able to create an working example (e.g. on jsbin.com) but if you did then I could try to see it...

Comment: Hi Sam - will join jsbin.com and attach a link back here. The variables that populate  the array come from the attributes of REST layers. The values are a coordinate string ( giving the geometry for the DXF file) and also the name array - which I use to name each unit in the dxf file as well. Be in touch

Comment: Hi Sam - the code is no exclusively mine so cannot post to jsbin. Any way to send by e-mail as a js file?

Comment: [Join me in this room for discussion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77319/room-for-gail-robertson-and-sam-onela)

Answer (score 2):

### Redundant unit strings

[**D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself](http://deviq.com/don-t-repeat-yourself/). It appears that each row follows a simple (yet lengthy) pattern. This can be simplified by pushing each result into an array, and then using [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to separate each unit by `dxfNextUnit`.

Also, the parentheses around each array element reference are unnecessary.

*Additionally* it appears that the code in the `for` loop over-writes each variable in each iteration. For example, if `graLyrUnits.graphics.length` is 16, then each of those variables gets assigned 16 times, which means every iteration except the last is superfluous!

The code below has the `for` loop removed, since there is no need to generate the units multiple times. I also [made this jsPerf test](https://jsperf.com/dxffileexportersimplification) for the sample three units in the example. The simplified code typically has ~8 times as many operations per second compared to the original code. I expect for 16 units it would be a much larger difference.

```js
function exportDXFUnits() {
  var unitCounter = graLyrUnits.graphics.length;
  if (unitCounter > 16) {
    alert("You can only select up to 16 units per dxf file");
  } else if (unitCounter > 0) {
    var dxfHeader = '  0\r\nSECTION\r\n  2\r\nENTITIES\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n';
    var dxfNextUnit = '  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n';
    var dxfCloser = '  0\r\nENDSEC\r\n  0\r\nEOF';
    var units = [];
    var last_coord = '85.0'; //from your comment: the 85 is part of the text notation of the dxf file that needs to be built around the values
    var coord_array; //declare once here, will be assigned within loop
    for (var i = 0; i < unitCounter; i++) {
      coord_array = graLyrUnits.graphics[i].attributes["Coords"].split(",");
      if (i > 0) {
        last_coord = coord_array[9];
      }
      units.push(coord_array[0] + '\r\n 20\r\n' + coord_array[1] + '\r\n 11\r\n' + coord_array[2] + '\r\n 21\r\n' + coord_array[3] + '\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n' + coord_array[2] + '\r\n 20\r\n' + coord_array[3] + '\r\n 11\r\n' + coord_array[4] + '\r\n 21\r\n' + coord_array[5] + '\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n' + coord_array[4] + '\r\n 20\r\n' + coord_array[5] + '\r\n 11\r\n' + coord_array[6] + '\r\n 21\r\n' + coord_array[7] + '\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n' + coord_array[6] + '\r\n 20\r\n' + coord_array[7] + '\r\n 11\r\n' + coord_array[8] + '\r\n 21\r\n' + coord_array[9] + '\r\n  0\r\nTEXT\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n 10\r\n' + coord_array[i] + '\r\n  20\r\n' + coord_array[1] + '\r\n  40\r\n' + last_coord + '\r\n  1\r\n' + graLyrUnits.graphics[i].attributes["name"] + '\r\n');
    }
    console.log(dxfHeader + units.join(dxfNextUnit) + dxfCloser);
    //download_file('data.dxf', 'text/dxf', dxfHeader + units.join(dxfNextUnit) + dxfCloser);
  } else {
    alert("You must select units to download");
  }
}
var graLyrUnits = {
  graphics: [{
    attributes: {
      Coords: "598412.0005,6634176.8235,598061.724,6634166.9087,598049.4625,6634630.8393,598399.6953,6634640.7534,598412.0005,6634176.8235",
      name: "60-00 N 103-00 W 91 D"
    }
  }, {
    attributes: {
      Coords: "598399.6953,6634640.7534,598049.4625,6634630.8393,598037.2004,6635094.7698,598387.3895,6635104.6832,598399.6953,6634640.7534",
      name: "60-00 N 103-00 W 91 E"
    }
  }, {
    attributes: {
      Coords: "598762.2773,6634186.7385,598412.0005,6634176.8235,598399.6953,6634640.7534,598749.9284,6634650.6675,598762.2773,6634186.7385",
      name: "60-00 N 103-00 W 91 C"
    }
  }]
};
exportDXFUnits();
```

One could also perhaps add each coordinate to an array and then join those with the new line characters (i.e. `\r\n`), and also utilize [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to construct `units`.

### Redundant variable declaration, assignment

I see these blocks:

> ```
> var string = dxfString;
> var coord_array = string.split(",");
> ```

and a few lines later:

> ```
> var string = dxfNameString;
> var name_array = string.split(",");
> ```

While it isn't wrong to use [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) again for the subsequent assignment of `string`, it could lead to confusion - the previous value won't be lost, though the variable has a new value assigned. Also, that variable isn't used more than once, so it could be eliminated:

```
var coord_array = dxfString.split(",");
```

and

```
var name_array = dxfNameString.split(",");
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this Sam. I cannot try it until I am back in the office next week - but will let you know how it goes. I cleans up the code by 75% and I knew that the repetition was something that could be dealt with by a more experienced person than my limited knowledge. Will go through and see how you processed it so I can learn how to do this for the future.  Much appreciated!

Comment: Yes - that for this redundant clean-up as well Sam - cheers. I knew the code was very bloated - so all recommendations are appreciated.